# Binding nested properties in Spring MVC forms

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I am having problem with binding nested object properties in Spring mvc 4. 
Here is the scenario:

Form.java:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "form")
public class Form implements java.io.Serializable{

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<Field> fieldsList = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<Field>(),  
           FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Field.class));
```

Field.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="field")
public class Field implements java.io.Serializable {

private FieldType fieldType;
```

FieldType.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="field_type")
public class FieldType implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private List<Field> fields;
```

I am sending a Form object having a list of Field objects:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editForm(HttpServletRequest request){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("denf_dynamic_form");
    Form f = formBackingObject(request);
    model.addObject("command", f);
    model.addObject("origFormName",f.getFormName());
    return model;
}
```

In JSP, I am trying to bind form.fieldsList.fieldType.name property like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${command.fieldsList}" var="fi" varStatus="i">

<spring:bind path="command.fieldsList[${i.index}].fieldType.name"> 
    <input style="display:none;" id='fTypeName' name='${status.expression}' 
    value="${status.value }"/>
</spring:bind>
```

The binding works fine if the list of fields is small. As the number of fields becomes larger (around 100), the behaviour becomes unusual; properties directly related to Form class are being bound correctly. But nested properties of FieldType class (like fieldType.name) cannot be bind.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update:
The reason for this is the identical ids generated for fieldType object.

[Basically they are referencing to same object. That is why spring bind is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqOb8.png)

Is there any way these ids can be unique?